# How to dispatch async actions in React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, dispatch

I have three redux actions. You can find them below:

```
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('twitter-token');
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    },
  };
  axios
    .get(`${url}/api/user`, config)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: USER_LOADED, payload: res.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: USER_NOTLOADED });
    });
};
```

```
export const loadTweets = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const token = getState().auth.token;
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    },
  };
  axios
    .get(`${url}/tweet`, config)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: TWEET_LOAD, payload: res.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: ADD_ERROR, payload: err.response.data });
    });
};
```

And the last one

```
export const getComments = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const token = getState().auth.token;
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    },
  };
  axios
    .get(`${url}/tweet/comments/${id}`, config)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: GET_COMMENT, payload: res.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: ADD_ERROR, payload: err.response.data });
    });
};
```

And I have dispatched them all in `App.js`

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser());
    dispatch(loadTweets());
    dispatch(getComments('all'));
  }, [dispatch]);
```

But before loadUser ends, loadTweets is getting executed. I want them to be dispatched by one by. How can I handle this? Can you help me, please?

Comment: May be you can await your axios request, so instead of using  ```axios.get().then().catch() ``` , you can use ```const response = await axios.get('/'); ```

Comment: Didn't help, [bruh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5780853/arslanshahab)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example for all of your code:

```js
export const loadUser = async () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('twitter-token');
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    },
  };
  await axios.get(`${url}/api/user`, config);
};
```

Comment: I have converted then().catch() to async/await. But it is not still working.

Comment: It didn't help [bruh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11336330/gustavo-moreira)